# Visual Studio 2015, Using 2015 Compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I have a simple question in which I think the answer is no as I can only find back wards compatibility with Visual Studio.

I was wondering can VS2015 use the latest C++ compiler offered with VS2015? I am running into issues with things like `to_string` not being defined, while I have a work around for all my issues I would like to code with simple function calls rather than use work arounds.

If anyone knows how to do this or can show me a trick for it please let me know!

PS I saw the `http://daffodil.codeplex.com/` and I see it only lets me set compiler settings for older versions of VS.

Comment: Yes, VS2015 comes with a new C++ compiler version. It's not hard to find [notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/19/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rtm.aspx) on what's new.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Platform Toolset to Visual Studio 2015.  Bring up the properties for your project, and on the General page you can specify the Platform Toolset.  If VS2015 isn't listed you installed the IDE but not the C++ compiler, or something got messed up in your install.